# Internal error message when calling a API Gateway based REST API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Need some help :) I have created a simple AWS API Gateway with a lambda backend just for trying it out. The only response is `{ "date": "2017-01-01" }`, and the only method accepted is `GET`. When I test the API in the AWS Console it works fine. The response is as expected. But when I try to access it externally I get an `Internal error message` response. It kind of blows of course. Do I have to setup a elastic IP for this to work? I shouldn't have to add any roles to the API Gateway (I assume) since the role only declares what resources the API Gateway should be allowed to access? Or is there a "external access" role of some kind? Ot do I have to provide any HTTP-header when accessing the API?

Comment: Did you deploy API?

Comment: Look in CloudWatch, your lambda function will be logging there.

Comment: You might add `Accept: application/json` to the request you're sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enable CORS if you accesing API from an external domain. Please see the screenshot below, which shows how to enable CORS

[image]